# SAS - proc import excel - first sheet

Tags: sas

Is there a way to import the first sheet from an excel file, without specifying the name of the sheet.

```
PROC IMPORT  
  DATAFILE= "filePath\fileName.xlsx" 
  DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE
  OUT= _fileName_OUT.;
  SHEET = 'sheetName';
  GETNAMES=YES;
  MIXED=NO;
  SCANTEXT=YES;
  USEDATE=YES;
  SCANTIME=YES;
RUN;
```

So instead of using the "sheetName" parameter, I am looking for a generic term that would specify that it should be the first sheet in the excel file.

Answer (score 4):

SAS automatically imports the "first" sheet in the excel file, for a certain definition of first, if you don't use the `sheet` statement.  So if you simply `proc import` the file without specifying sheet, you'll get whatever the first is.  But it won't be necessarily the left-most; it's the first in Excel's internal thinking.

Also, the dbms you use matters.  `EXCEL` and `XLSX` do different things.  `EXCEL` seems to take the original `SHEET1`; `XLSX` seems to take the left most sheet, by default.

Comment: unfortunately, that does not work.
ERROR: Expecting a valid sheet name or range name.

Comment: Did you leave `sheet` in there and just not give it a value?  I meant to leave off the `sheet` statement entirely.  That certainly works.

Comment: I just commented out the sheet statement and ran the script and got the error... maybe it has to do with the SAS version (I have SAS 9.3), but it's not working for me - I have to either define a RANGE or a SHEET.

Comment: No, this has worked since 9.1.3 at least; I've done it since then.  Sheet has never been mandatory... something else is going on, or you have something complex in your environment that you're not explaining.